# How to dynamically change the Spinner's items

Tags: android, dynamic, android-spinner

I have two spinners. Country and City.
I want to dynamically change the City's values upon Country selection.
I know how to create and initialize the values of Country but don't know how to set and change the City's values.

Any guidance is appreciated.

**UPDATES1**
The problem is, I don't have idea on how to update the content of City Spinner. I know listener and other basics on how to create a fixed spinner.

Comment: I am thinking of Spinner.getAdapter() then use clear() to remove existing items then .add() to add new items. But unfortunately, can't find the two methods. Looks strange to me because I am using ArrayAdapter. It should have add() and clear() -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add%28T%29

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the second spinner, use an Adapter over a `List<String>` (or whatever your City representation is). After changing the contents of the list, call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter, and that will do.

Comment: @eros: Sure, `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: "Notifies the attached View that the underlying data has been changed and it should refresh itself." <- 1) its automatically refresh? 2) do I need to declare my adapter as Activity instance variable?

Comment: I declare my City's adapter as Activty's instance variable. Then utilize, clear() & add().Afterwards, call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). If you have better approach, please share it here.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get a programmatic reference to the spinner, something like this:

```
     Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
     ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then to update your city's values, use an OnItemSelectedListener, like this:

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
      View view, int pos, long id) {
          //update content of your city spinner using the value at index,
          // id, or the view of the selected country. 
      }
   }

   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
   // Do nothing.
   }
```

}

Finally, you need to bind the listener to the country spinner like this:

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

see here for reference: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

Comment: would you share on how to update content of your city spinner?